# How to manage multi database dynamic architecture in Node.js

Tags: node.js, multi-tenant

I have database 1, 2, 3, ....n
In node API getting some unique code and based on that i can identify database connection detail.
now im confuse in setting db object in global object or not.

I tried with global variable, but in some point this variable change by any other API call

Comment: Hi, please tell us more: what libraries are you using? Do you have requirements on connection disposal?